# unable to install ai4ai4bharat-transliteration

Tags: python, transliteration, indic

I am unable to install ai4bharat-transliteration
while installing I faced this issue :

DEPRECATION: omegaconf 2.0.6 has a non-standard dependency specifier PyYAML>=5.1.*. pip 24.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of omegaconf or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at pypa/pip#12063

I have installed Visual C++ build tools since the issue is not solved
refer this https://github.com/AI4Bharat/IndicXlit/issues/21

Comment: py -m pip install ai4bharat-transliteration

Comment: @toyotaSupra It doesn't work.
I am still facing the same error